# Preventing access to seo-unfriendly URLs and redirect to seo-friendly (canonical) URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, friendly-url

I see many similar questions but none helped me so far:

I have the logic of my script under /song/song.php?url=lang/params (seo-unfriendly URL). I use this rewrite to have a friendly URL and load the content from the seo-unfriendly one, using a parameter to differentiate between languages:

```
 RewriteRule ^songs-and-chords/(.*?)(/*)?$ /song/song.php?url=en/$1 [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^canzoni-e-accordi/(.*?)(/*)?$ /song/song.php?url=it/$1 [NC,L]
```

Now I want to prevent access to /song/song.php, forcing a redirect to the seo-friendly one, so something like this, using the %{THE_REQUEST} to make external redirect:

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*?song/song\.php\?url=it/(\S*) [NC]
 RewriteRule /canzoni-e-accordi/$1 [R,L]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*?song/song\.php\?url=en/(\S*) [NC]
 RewriteRule /songs-and-chords/$1 [R,L]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*?song/song\.php.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule /songs-and-chords/ [R,L]
```

But non of this rules is executed... What am I doing wrong? How can I debug this in a good way?

(I already use rel="canonical" in the song.php script but still I would prefer the script to be not accessible at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is, the pattern of your `RewriteRule` statements is missing. Also, the rewritten URLs would be using `%1` reference and not `$1`.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /song/song\.php\?url=it/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /canzoni-e-accordi/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /song/song\.php\?url=en/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /songs-and-chords/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /song/song\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /songs-and-chords/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. The only problem is: this URL
/song/song.php?url=it/pink-floyd/the-wall
Redirects to 
/canzoni-e-accordi/pink-floyd/the-wall?url=it/pink-floyd/the-wall
How can I get rid of the attached url parameter? The QSA flag is not set so where does it come from? (and what is the "\ " after GET)?

Comment: @Fabbio Changing `%1` to `%1?` will fix the added query string in redirected url. As for `GET\ ` string; the request send to the server is of the form: `GET /song/song.php?url=it/pink-floyd/the-wall HTTP/1.1`. I am escaping the space after `GET`. You can also use `\s` instead of `\ `

Comment: Works like a charm! But I am a bit lost now... What is the meaning of %1? It's not regex stuff, right? It is also not clear to me why I should start a RewriteRule with "^ ". Can you suggest any good documentation page about these issues?

Comment: @Fabbio https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteRule ; `%1` means the matched group from `RewriteCond` statement and `$1` means matched group from `RewriteRule`s. When using `^` in rewriterule, I am ignoring the url entirely (which is not needed anyways as I am handling the raw request).